# Google App Engine - owned relationship scalability problem

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Google documentation describes the ability of the google app engine to store owned relationships using Collections. In the example below we have an Employee object having a List of ContactInfo objects. The problem I am having is that in order to add a new ContactInfo object to the List we have to retrieve ALL previous ContactInfo objects. They will get retrieved as soon as we touch the contactInfoList. If the Employee has lots of contacts a simple add operation would require lots of overhead. Am I missing something?

```
public class Employee {

 @PrimaryKey
 @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
 private Long id;

 @Persistent(mappedBy = "employee")
        private List<ContactInfo> contactInfoList = new ArrayList<ContactInfo>();
```

Comment: Have you found an answer to this? Can unowned relationships be the only way?!

Answer (score 0):

You can instead save the new ContactInfo object after setting its employee property. It will be added to the list the next time Employee is loaded.

Comment: It would solve the problem but it doesn't work. Creation of the new ContactInfo with the Employee property set, doesn't add the newly created ContactInfo to the List on the Employee object. I just run a quick test to confirm that. It only works when I specifically add the object to the List and persist the Employee. Maybe the owned relationships are to be used only in situations when all the data is present during the parent object creation?